# handling database error with ajax request codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, error-handling, ajaxform

I am intentionally making error i.e. using one of the coulmn's name wrong to learn how to handle the error with ajax call with codeigniter.

#### Last Comment in controller function at the end is my question/problem

**My AJX Code** is following. I am using **[ajaxform plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)**. It shows me all response from controller perfectly but problem is only

#### I am unable to get response from model in controller while using ajax call that is little weird

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm
({
    success: function(responseText)
    {
        if(responseText != "1")         
            $('#feedback').html(responseText);          
    }
});
```

Following is snapshot of exact error which i can see in console but unable to get in controller and hence in view. It describes complete error i.e unknown column in given query, but i captured only upper portion.

[image]

My **model function** is below

```
public function updateItem($id, $data, $tbl)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $r = $this->db->update($tbl, $data);
    if($r)
        return $r;
    else
    {
        $r = $this->db->_error_message();
        return  $r;
    }
}
```

My **controller function** code

```
public function upadteme()
{
    $r = $this->ajax_model->updateItem($uid, $data, 'users');
    echo $r." -- "; // Unable to get this echo working 
    //when using ajaxcall (calling controller through ajax) otherwise fine
}
```

Comment: Please post the ajax code.

Comment: I think this is a great way to learn something, kudos to you on that one! I agree though, please post the AJAX code. I'm assuming you don't have a "failure" clause in your AJAX code. Are you using a library of any sort? If you're using raw AJAX, just do a conditional on response code 500

Comment: I'm also searching for a solution for this problem. Thanks @Sami

Comment: Added the ajax code and got the perfect answer as well..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the class will not populate `_error_message` if `db_debug` is on which it appears to be by default.

In `config/database.php`, set

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

and try again.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot...I had nothing like `$db['default']['db_debug'] ` in my config/databas.php, but i added the line `$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;`

When i saw the answer i was surprised what is this that how it can work, but its working perfectly :). Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. I think by default it is `TRUE` so you need to do as you did and explicitly set it to `FALSE`.

Comment: I have got my problem fixed but question is still open.

Could you please add little more (or i should open another question) that why i get this error al-right when doing work without ajax and even with ajax i get it in console but not in controller and as ajax respose-text in my view. I Also get 500 internal error, u can see the image

Comment: You can look through system/database/DB_driver.php and related files to see where the issue is. If you notice, the error returned in `_error_message` and the error that gets displayed as in your screenshot are very different. The `_error_message` will just contain the error string whereas the displayed version will have styling, etc. It appears that if `debug` is on, it displays the error and exits, not getting to the point where it would populate `_error_message`. I'm not sure why -- it might be a bug. 500 is the status set by CI - appropriate because it's an internal server error.